# video in html5 is not working in all browser

Tags: html, wordpress, video, tags

I tried this code but video is just continuing to load, not to playing.

I also tried video codec H-264 but that is not working.

Next I tried to convert mp4 video to webm but that did not help either

Can anyone tell me how to do this using jquery and ajax?

```html
<video controls muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript/jQuery coming into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked by drag and drop to open the movie.mp4 or the movie.ogg file?
If the file does not work by simply opening it using a browser, it might be the file's problem, not the code or the browser.

For the file type support per browsers please refer the "Can I use?" pages:

[MPEG-4/H.264](https://caniuse.com/mpeg4)
[Ogg/Theora](https://caniuse.com/?search=ogg)

Comment: Please can you tell me in proper way?

Comment: How can i used https://caniuse.com/?search=ogg and what is the 4-85, 86, 87-89?

Comment: sorry i have no idea about that can you tell me in brief i hope you understand thank you

Comment: @NiharFuerte Sure, the video files itself not in the same format even if the file uses the same extension, There are more specs of video file to concern. if the file uses the H.264 format there's video codec, audio codec, profile, level, bitrate limitation. so I think it would be good to use video encoders like [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) re-encode the source videos to the most commonly used spec. Then the browser would playback the re-encoded files.

Comment: @NiharFuerte the numbers you would see from the caniuse page are the browser versions. for example, the ogg files would be played without any plugin or extensions in the IE browser from version 9, and the current IE version 10 also supports it. and the Edge browser supports from version 12 and the current Edge version 86 supports it ... something like that.